# Appcelerator iPod build problems

Tags: iphone, build, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I'm using Titanium Studio (1.0.0.201104272233) and Titanium Developer (1.2.2) and have just begun my app development. It builds just fine to the iPhone simulator. Yay! BUT. . . when I attempt to build to the device, I get this error:

> [INFO] Performing clean build
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.0/iphone/builder.py", line 1306, in main
>       execute_xcode("iphoneos%s" % iphone_version,args,False)
>     File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.0/iphone/builder.py", line 1066, in execute_xcode
>       output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
>   File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.0/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
>       sys.exit(rc)
>   SystemExit: 65

Here's the full build log: [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/1872240)

I'm using OSX 10.6.7, Titanium SDK 1.7.0, ios SDK 4.2 (or 4.3). I have xCode3 in /Developer and xCode4 in /xCode4/ and a receding hairline from this issue. I'm trying to build to an iPod touch with software version 4.3.3.

Studio seems to handle the parallel location of xCode4 better than Developer when working on the simulator. I've deleted the build folder a number of times and attempted different ios/Titanium SDKs.

Comment: can you build it in Xcode? `/build/iphone/*.xcodeproject`?

Comment: No, when i tried, it told me that I have multiple signing identities and it is choosing the expired one. It also had a code signing error. I never knew I could build that file in xCode. You're hint is awesome and I'll post when I get it built!

Comment: This helped me out [link](http://ericholsinger.com/programming/xcode-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-expired-certificates-causing-ambiguous-matches/) even though it took a bunch of cycles to get all the expired certs removed from the keychain(s). You're a winner Brian!

Comment: Got it!  I'll post my answer after the time out.

Comment: I struggled with this and possibly lost some hair myself for days before I found a working solution, expired certificates should show by default... smooth move Jobs ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this is that one can use the *.xcodeproject file and go to build the application in xCode. This will give the developer a whole different debugging environment with error messages particular to the iPod/Apple requirements and certifications to get all the settings right. Though they may appear to be correct and accurate in Titanium Studio or Developer, there can still be errors or conflicts. In my case, I had duplicate certificates in my keychain and some errors in my provisioning set up which, as you can see in the log wasn't apparent at all from Titanium Studio or Developer.

Thanks a bunch Brian for your assisting question and guidance.